# AppleScript K750 Toggle Fn Keys

Tags: applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, logitech

I'm new on AppleScript, and I'm trying to make a keyboard shortcut to toggle Fn Keys on my Logitech K750. I use AutoCAD and really need it.

I started to to try some codes, but till now no success... can anybody help me?

Here is the code...

Thank you!!!

`tell application "Device Manager"
    activate
end tell
tell application "Device Manager"
    get every attribute of checkbox "When this box is checked, press F1, F2, etc. keys to use the standard function keys, and press and hold the Fn key to use the enhanced functions printed on the keys." of window "Wireless Solar Keyboard K750 for Mac"
    click checkbox "When this box is checked, press F1, F2, etc. keys to use the standard function keys, and press and hold the Fn key to use the enhanced functions printed on the keys." of window "Wireless Solar Keyboard K750 for Mac"
        activate
    if value of checkbox "When this box is checked, press F1, F2, etc. keys to use the standard function keys, and press and hold the Fn key to use the enhanced functions printed on the keys." of window "Wireless Solar Keyboard K750 for Mac" = 0 then
            display dialog "Standard Function Keys off..." giving up after 1
    else
        display dialog "Standard Function Keys on..." giving up after 1
    end if
end tell
tell application "Device Manager"
    quit
end tell`

Answer (score 0):

This script clicks on the function key checkbox.

It is tested and OK on ElCapitain (10.11):

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of current pane
end tell
delay 0.5 -- to make sure system has time to open the window !
tell application "System Events"
tell application process "System Preferences" to click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of front window
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to close front window
```

Warning : the GUI scripting depends of the current system version. If Apple change the layout of preferences panes in next OS version, this script may no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question, and this answer doesn't strictly address the question about AppleScript, but this thread was a top Google result for the general issue of toggling the Fn key on the Logitech K750 Solar Mac keyboard.

The solution I found for that general issue was to install the new-ish [Logitech Options](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893) utility. Once that's installed and open, select the keyboard and toggle the checkbox next to **Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys** to get your desired Fn key functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, pbell!
But that works only with an Apple Keyboard.
Mine is a Logitech K750, and the Fn Key option is located on "Logitech Device Manager", an app From Logitech.
I've managed to make it working till when the "Logitech Device Manager" opens... so, after, I have to manually click on the check box...

[Logitech Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V95uf.png)

Comment: Oups ! Then try to use syntax in device manager similar to the syntax of my script. First to make the script easier to read, replace the description on the checkbox by a number (I guess =1 based on your screen copy). Also instruction 'click checkbox...' must inside a 'tell application "System Events" / tell process "Device Manager"... bloc (see my script). That's the way you can simulate clicks ad other GUI actions via script. Last remark is your display dialog should not be in tell device manager bloc, which may not support it. just put the display dialog after the end tell.